# Is there anywhere I can find examples of letters seeking interpretation of FARs, sent to the FAA Office of Chief Counsel?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa

Is there anywhere I may find examples of letters seeking interpretation of FARs, sent to the FAA Office of Chief Counsel?

What is the appropriate salutation, if one is needed, on a letter to the FAA Office of Chief Counsel?

Should the actual letter (not the envelope) be sent to the "Chief Counsel" or to the "Office of Chief Counsel"?

Should anything in the way letter is addressed, or who it is addressed to, signal that I specifically am seeking clarification of an FAR and not raising some other legal issue?

Related:

[How can someone get clarification from the FAA on the intent of a regulation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/how-can-someone-get-clarification-from-the-faa-on-the-intent-of-a-regulation)

https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/key_officials/media/AGC_Org_Chart.pdf

Comment: Future edit-- better wording for title "Where can I find"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAA posts the original submission along with the interpretations, at least for [recent interpretations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/RIIndex.cfm). There's a lot of variation in who they're addressed to; many of them are follow-ups to previous contact with the FAA, presumably with the local FSDO.

[This one (Standel-West Coast Aviation Services, 2019)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2019/Standel-West%20Coast%20Aviation%20Services%20-%20(2019)%20Legal%20Interpretation.pdf) might be useful as a starting point, it simply uses the salutation "To Whom It May Concern" and it has the full mailing address in it. It also uses very specific wording about the scope of the request:

> This letter is a request for interpretation and clarification of 14
>   C.F.R. § 135.267(b).